# Как сделать кривую без canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Собственно, как сделать кривую без `canvas`?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вам нужен SVG? Вот там есть примеры кривых https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 1):

Без `canvas`  - никак

Хотя... если всего десяток статических линий, тогда можно создать свои шрифты-линии и преобразовывать нужные линии так, как Вам нужно